# How to use multiple wildcards with $wpdb prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, prepared-statement

I'm trying to dynamically build a prepared statement for use with Wordpress, which currently works fine as long as only a single field has a value, but fails to return results if multiple values are present. The code is below:

```
$keywords = ($_POST['keywords']) ? 'post_title LIKE %s' : '';
$keywordsVal = (!empty($keywords)) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';

$location = ($_POST['town']) ? 'post_city LIKE %s' : '';
$locationVal = (!empty($location)) ? $_POST['town'] : '';

$orgName = ($_POST['org_name']) ? 'post_title LIKE %s' : '';
$orgNameVal = (!empty($orgName)) ? $_POST['org_name'] : '';

$countyName = ($_POST['county']) ? 'post_region LIKE %s' : '';
$countyNameVal = (!empty($countyName)) ? $_POST['county'] : '';

$postcode = ($_POST['postcode']) ? 'post_zip LIKE %s' : '';
$postcodeVal = (!empty($postcode)) ? $_POST['postcode'] : '';

$queryArray = array($keywords => $keywordsVal, $location => $locationVal, $orgName => $orgNameVal, $countyName => $countyNameVal, $postcode => $postcodeVal);

$queryString = array();
$queryVals = array();
foreach($queryArray AS $string => $val) {
    if (!empty($string)) {
        $queryString[] = $string;
        $queryVals[] = '%'.$wpdb->esc_like($val).'%';
        }
    }

$groupStrings = implode(' AND ', $queryString);
$groupVals = implode(', ', $queryVals);

$searchQuery = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_geodir_gd_place_detail WHERE
    $groupStrings
    "
    ,$groupVals
    )
);
```

If a single value is entered, it will produce a query string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geodir_gd_place_detail WHERE post_city LIKE %s ,%london%
```

This works absolutely fine and returns results as expected. However, if more than one value is present it simply does not work. For example, the code produced when two values are entered looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geodir_gd_place_detail WHERE post_title LIKE %s AND post_city LIKE %s ,%sushi%, %london%
```

This fails to return results, even though if I manually take that query and run it directly in phpMyAdmin like thus:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geodir_gd_place_detail WHERE post_title LIKE '%sushi%' AND post_city LIKE '%london%'
```

It successfully returns results as expected! My guess is the problem lies somewhere with using LIKE wildcards and wpdb prepared statements, but I am at a loss as to exactly what.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the multiple value queries?

Comment: No, simply no results are returned.